# Netezza: how to save select results

Tags: sql, netezza

Suppose that I have table R1=(A, B, C, D) and R2=(X, Y).

How do I save the following result to a (temporary) table

```
select * from R1, R2 where R1.A=R2.X       (1)
```

Similarly, what if I want to save a select result to an variable, e.g.

```
select avg(C) from from R1, R2 where R1.A=R2.X   (2)
```

Also, what is the best elegant query to join two tables while change the name of some fields, e.g. what is the shortest equivalent of query (3)?

```
 select A, B, C, D, X as E, Y as F from from R1, R2 where R1.A=R2.X   (3)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(1) Create Temp Table tbl1 as
select * from R1 inner join
R2 on R1.A=R2.X 
distribute on random

(2) Create Temp Table tbl2 as
select avg(c) as avg_c from R1 inner join
R2 on R1.A=R2.X 
distribute on random
```

(3) Using `as` is a fine way to rename a resulting column/field